# keeping example index correspondence with tf.keras.predict and tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using the tf.keras API in TensorFlow2. I have 100,000 images or so that are saved as TFRecords (128 images per record). Each record has an input image, target image, and frame index. I can't find a clean way to keep the frame index with the prediction.

Here is an example, except I build a dataset with NumPy arrays instead of reading from TFRecords:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

# build dummy tf.data.Dataset
x = np.random.random(10000).astype(np.float32)
y = x + np.random.random(10000).astype(np.float32) * 0.1
idx = np.arange(10000, dtype=np.uint16)
np.random.shuffle(idx)  # frames are random in my TFRecord files
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y, idx))
# pretend ds returned from TFRecord
ds = ds.map(lambda f0, f1, f2: (f0, f1))  # strip off idx
ds = ds.batch(32)

# build and train model
x = keras.Input(shape=(1,))
y_hat = keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)  # i.e. linear regression
model = keras.Model(x, y_hat)
model.compile('sgd', 'mse')
history = model.fit(ds, epochs=5)

# predict 1 batch
model.predict(ds, steps=1)
```

Short of reading through the dataset again to extract the indices (which is prone to error), is there a clean way to keep prediction correspondence with image index? In TF1.x it was straightforward. But I'd like to take advantage of clean Keras compile(), fit(), predict() API in TF2.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, was thinking too hard, pretty easy actually. Just add index to dataset when you are making predictions, and pull out indices as you are iterating through batches:

```
rt tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

def build_dataset(mode):
    np.random.seed(1)
    x = np.random.random(10000).astype(np.float32)
    y = x + np.random.random(10000).astype(np.float32) * 0.1
    idx = np.arange(10000, dtype=np.uint16)
    if mode == 'train':
        ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
        ds = ds.shuffle(128)
    else:
        ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, idx))
    ds = ds.batch(32)

    return ds

# build and train simple linear regression model
x_tf = keras.Input(shape=(1,))
yhat_tf = keras.layers.Dense(1)(x_tf)
model = keras.Model(x_tf, yhat_tf)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
ds = build_dataset('train')
history = model.fit(ds, epochs=5)

# predict 1 batch
ds = build_dataset('predict')
for batch in ds:
    x_tf, indices_tf = batch 
    yhat_np = model.predict(x_tf)
    break
```